# Entify Framework: Is it legal to reuse an entity added to a disposed context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have created an Entity Framework entity1 and added it to dbContext1.
I then, for any reason, Dispose of dbContext1 and create a fresh DbContext2.

Is it OK to now reuse entity1 by adding it to dbContext2?

EF Version is 6.1.3.

```
public class DbSaver
{
    MyDbContext _context;

    public DbSaver()
    {
        MyDbContext _context = new MyDbEntities();
    }

    public void MustDoSave(/*whatever*/)
    {
        bool saved = false;

        MyEntity entity1 = new MyEntity() { /*setup entity field values here*/ };
        _context.Add(entity1);

        while (!saved)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
                saved = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                _context.Dispose();   // dispose the original context ("contextA)
                _context = new MyDbEntities(); // create a fresh one

                // the questionable part:
                _context.Add(entity1); // is it legal to now reuse an entity previously added to the old context ("contextB")??

                Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait before fresh retry
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have all the code to just try it out :) Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a tricky question. If the changes were persisted, then the entity will have identity field populated. Don't assume that it will *not* be populated just because the transaction has been rolled back - that is the implementation detail of the `DbContext` class.

Consequently, if you add the same entity to the new `DbContext` assuming that it is still new, i.e. without its identity field populated, you might get into troubles when you try to persist changes for the second time.

My advice is not to do that, since correctness of your code then depends on implementation details of Entity Framework. Needless to say, implementation may change in the future and then your code which seems to be working fine today will stop working tomorrow.

Comment: that's a good point, but let's ignore that for a second (or assume the DB is queried whether the entry was added before re-adding). Is there some formal definition of whether the entity reuse itself is 'legal'

Comment: There is definitely no physical constraint with using the entity any way you like, including giving it to another context. `DbContext` is there only to detect changes and persist them on request. Anyway, beware of the hidden traps, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, as the entity does not keep a reference to the context (or contexts) that it is currently associated with.